# Git in Visual Studio - 1 Repo is a mess, 1 is good - how do I force the good one to become 'prime'?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bitbucket, visual-studio-community

I wont go into too many details but due to a merge conflict somehow I've managed to get 1 of 2 machines that subscribe to the same Repo into an out of date mess.

The other machine is fine - and I'd like that to become the recognised 'correct' version of the repo from this point forward.

How can I make that version just overwrite the one on Bitbucket - and on the machine that's in a mess?

I can't see any way of doing this in Visual Studio and am not sure what to search for in Google?

Obviously I don't want to risk merging the two copies and losing the only good version of the Repo I have. I'd also rather not have to re-create the Repo - that seems a bit drastic.

Thanks.